# WooCommerce: Change some categories price to be by Weight

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the price display on WooCommerce for categories 'beef' and 'chicken' by adding "per kg" after the actual price in product page.

I have the following code but it doesn't work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wb_change_product_html' );
// Change and return $price_html variable using the $price and weight amount
function wb_change_product_html( $price, $product ) {

$product_categories = array('beef', 'chicken');

    if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )

    $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . $price . ' per kg </span>'; // change weight measurement here

    return $price_html;
}
```

Could you please help me to resolve it ?

Many thanks for your support.

Comment: Try adding `{` at the end of line `if( has_term....` and `}` after `return $price...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'bbloomer_add_price_suffix', 99, 4 );

function bbloomer_add_price_suffix( $html, $product, $price, $qty ){
    $product_categories = array('beef', 'chicken');
    if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $html = ' per kg';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for the product page but I also want to display it in the cart page:


add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'wb_change_product_price_cart' );
// Change and return $price_html variable using the $price and weight amount
function wb_change_product_html( $price, $product ) {

$product_categories = array('beef', 'chicken');

    if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )

 $price = $price . ' per kg'; // change weight measurement here

 return $price;
}